# Selenium - Element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Needing help on this problem. All solutions/suggestions I have researched do not fix it.

Trying to click a button with Selenium. Keep getting these errors.
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLButtonElement] has no size and location`
and `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

I am not understanding why this element is not interactable.

```
    play_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ppp"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(play_button).click(play_button).perform()
```

When printing `play_button` = `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ca50b37ee2e4b194b2ad5305e254079f", element="78e35dc3-fef8-4082-a6e4-0a92dfbf2ec6")>`

I have tried `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ppp"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button')))` but this times out. Element never becomes clickable.

I have tried using the full xpath.

I have tried disabling extensions/maximize window driver options.

The element is not in a frame or anything. It lies in a div that lies in the body.
The element is clickable within Chrome's console.

Any information/suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: I have suggested some answer, but it would be better if you could share the page link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button you are trying to click is hidden, not clickable even with JavaScript executor.
You can start video on that page clicking on

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.player-poster.clickable').click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.play-wrapper').click()
```

No need to use `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element` etc.
Just a simple click.
Just don't forget setting

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Or using an explicitly wait of expected conditions to make page loaded before accessing the element.

Comment: First solution - Gave same error of `element not interactable: [object HTMLButtonElement] has no size and location` on line .move_to_element

Comment: Second solution - did nothing at all..... Would this mean the element isnt clickable to being with? whats confusing is I can get the element within Chrome's console and click it but not when ejecting js? Idk. thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Maybe it is inside an iframe? Can you share a link?

Comment: maybe shadow DOM?

Comment: Try clicking by this css_selector `div.player-poster.clickable`

Comment: The button you are trying to click is hidden, not clickable even with JS

Comment: Thank you for your help you fixed it. `poster = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.player-poster.clickable')` then `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(poster).click(poster).perform()` youre a life saver thank you so much.

Comment: I am sorry to bother again. What element do I need to get to make this page fullscreen the video. It was working fine the day of. Idk what happened. https://sports24.icu/tv/v?id=nfln

Comment: When the video is started the button to open the full screen is `//button[@aria-label='fullscreen']` XPath. With css it will be `button[aria-label='fullscreen']`

Comment: thanks for responding. Both are giving me `no size and location` errors. I can click the element within console: `document.querySelector('button[aria-label="fullscreen"]').click()` I am getting the element by xpath `fullscreen_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='fullscreen']")`

Comment: Have you added expected condition, kind of `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='fullscreen']"))).click()` ?
`

Answer (score 0):

Using full XPath solved this problem for me.